# Creating a square identity matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Write a function called `identity` that creates a square identity matrix, which is a matrix whose elements are 0 except for the elements on the diagonal (from top left to bottom right) which have a value of 1. The diagonal consists of those elements whose row and column indexes are the same: (1,1), (2,2), etc.

The function takes one positive integer input argument, which is the size of the matrix, and returns the matrix itself as an output argument.

For example, `identity(4)` must return a 4-by-4 identity matrix.

You are not allowed to use the built-in `eye` or `diag` functions.

(Hint: you can index into a matrix with a single index and MATLAB will handle it as if it was a vector using column-major order.)

Comment: This is easy to achieve and sounds like homework. Where is your research effort? Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question after. Show what you have tried so far and what your thoughts are to solve this problem.

Comment: Or you can do like this `fix(corrcoef(rand(10,10)))` :) It is not a good way, but it will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it in two simple lines and without `zeros`... The first line creates a `n x n` matrix where all elements are `0`. After you can (as your hint says) address the elements with a single argument. The distance between the ones in the identity matrix are `n+1`. This way you write the ones with the mentioned distance until the end.

```
function out = identity(n)
    out(n,n)       = 0;
    out(1:n+1:end) = 1;
end
```

Comment: Do you know, if there is a performance difference between `A(n,n)=0` and `A=zeros(n)`?

Comment: Oh wow, I just tested this, and for `N=10000`, your approach takes 0.000255 seconds, while `zeros(N)` takes 1.106566 seconds. I always thought, that the standard way was to use `zeros(N)`.

Comment: @sonystarmap Check out [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) article on Undocumented Matlab. Don't miss the section «Variants for pre-allocation».

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the basics:

```
function M = identity(n)
    M = zeros(n);
    for i=1:n
        M(i,i) = 1;
    end
end
```

Pretty much the same code as any other language...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can use the built-in function `zeros()`, a possible implementation of the `eye()` funtion is the following one:

```
function matrix = identity(n)
    out = zeros(n);
    idx = 1:n+1:n^2;
    out(idx) = 1;
    matrix = out;
end
```