# Matlab allocating A=zeros(N) vs. A(N,N)=0 yields strange performance results

Tags: performance, matlab, memory-management

I stumbled upon the [answer of Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669403/creating-a-square-identity-matrix) in a thread about creating identity matrices with Matlab.
He uses

```
A(N,N) = 0
```

to allocate a `NxN` matrix with zero entries. I've always used

```
A= zeros(N)
```

I was wondering, which of the two ways is faster and have written the following small test script.

```
function compare


N =2.^[1:14];


T1 = zeros(length(N),1);
for i=1:length(N)
    clear A
    n =N(i);
    tic
    A(n,n) = 0;
    t=toc;
    T1(i) = t;
end

T2 = zeros(length(N),1);
for i=1:length(N)
    clear A
    n =N(i);
    tic
    A=zeros(n);
    t=toc;
    T2(i) = t;
end




figure
loglog(N,T1,'r');
hold on
loglog(N,T2,'g');
title('Runtime for memory allocation');
legend('A(N,N)=0', 'A=zeros(N)','Location','SouthEast');
xlabel('N');
ylabel('Runtime')


end
```

Which simply measures the time for memory allocation via the two different ways. Here is the result:

[image]

This means, that for small `N`, both methods are equally fast, but for `N>1000`, the time to allocate a matrix with `A(N,N)=0` actually drops? I'm unable to explain this result and would be happy to hear some opinions on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) post from Yair Altman's website that's quite interesting and should answer a few interrogations

Comment: Thanks, this explains why one method is faster than the other. However, I'm still not sure what's happening at N=1000?

Comment: It's likely going to be difficult for anyone to answer that question without having knowledge of MATLAB's internals.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea haha maybe someone here will enlighten us :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169222/faster-way-to-initialize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication-matlab

Comment: @Benoit_11 The results of the OP is very consistent with the page you referenced, and also with [this one](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2). He argues about some effect of SIMD ... not the reason IMO. Hope a Mathworks guy will hear you ... :)

Comment: @JensBoldsen Following one of the answer, the reason seems to lie under the allocation scheme of the OS. I tend to agree with it ... but I cannot find it, need more search.